# How to prevent push branch on git when someone elso pushed before?

Tags: git

I would apply a git hook rule, to avoid "branch out, and merge in" when during `person A` does commit and push someone else, `person B` pushes.

Is it a way to check if my change is not on the head of a remote branch, I should not able to push?

Comment: By default, clients have to force-push to erase the history in the destination repository. Are you saying that these default settings are not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to solve this by implementing a git workflow in your organization. As @j6t mentioned in the comment, by default someone will have to force-push if the tip of their current branch is behind their remote counterpart.

So my suggestion is

- Never force-push unless you really know what you are doing
- Use `rebase` as a local cleanup method.  - This is a well-known workflow pattern

Essentially what the second point means is that you can locally rebase the branch against the remote master (or whatever your target branch is) before submitting the pull request (or directly pushing to it).  This will make sure that the conflicts only happen in your local and the remote repo will be clean.